# ASP.NET MVC 4 Website not allowing URL to query the database on the production Server

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, windows

This is the one the weirdest problem I have encountered with ASP.NET MVC 4 Website. The Website works perfectly on the development server, and when I originally deployed it to the production server it gave no problems. I made a few changes with the store procedure that it uses, and upgraded the Website on the production server, however this is where my problems begin. It works fine on the development server (VS 2012 for Web), but when I run it on the production server (Windows Server 2008 R2 (SE) with SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition) it refuses to allow me to query the database using the URL with a name value pair. eq. http://myexample.com/Home.aspx/Document?code=46 Why does this happen? I am clueless. By the way I checked the security for the logins in MS SQL Server, plus it was working before I upgraded the Website. All I want it to do is fetch a pdf document from the database and download it to the client workstation.

Comment: Can you give us some relevant code?

Comment: why the url `htme.aspx/document?code=46` include the slash right after the aspx ? - maybe the url security of the iss is preventing.

Comment: @Erwin here is part of code that queries the database      cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
              Convert.ToInt32(code);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    image = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
                    ms = new MemoryStream(image, 0, image.Length);

Comment: @Aristos I changed the route routine to use Home.aspx for the website. I figure IIS 6.1 may have issues with MVC naming convention. Btw How do you check IIS url security?

Comment: I notice that the stored procedure is not executed on the production server when I trace it with the SQL Profiler, however i see it run on the development server. How do I configure IIS to allow store procedure to run on the web server?

Answer (score 0):

When you have check all angles, such as permission rights and the logic in the code and yet the problem still persist. Do a restart of the database server instance. That may just fix the problem.